# Is it possible to update objects on events from other classes?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have two classes for two different objects (`mirror`, `beam`). `mirror` is drawn based on a slider/scale, and `beam` is initially drawn based on a `mirror`'s attribute, calculated and updated based on other `mirror` attributes. I've found a way to redraw `mirror` on slider change, but not `beam`. What do I do?

`mirror` is passed a slider on creation, and then an attribute is created (`self.distSlider = distSlider`). I've tried passing the entirety of `mirror` to `beam` (as the dependent attribute requires some other atrributes of `mirror`), and also creating an atrribute from this slider, but update event from `beam` overrides the update event from `mirror`. Passing the slider only to both objects has the same result.

```py
from tkinter import *

def drawCoords(point, distance):
    mirrorX = distance;
    mirrorY = point.y;
    mirrorLen = 50;
    return [mirrorX, mirrorY - mirrorLen, mirrorX, mirrorY + mirrorLen], mirrorLen;

def midpoint(coords):
    return Point(round((coords[2]+coords[0])/2),round((coords[3]+coords[1])/2));

class GUI:
    def __init__(self,master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
        bg = Canvas(frame, width = 400, height = 400, background = "#F0F0F0", borderwidth = 3, relief = SUNKEN)
        bg.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
        dist = Scale(frame, from_ = 100, to = 200, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        dist.pack(fill = X, expand = 1)

class Mirror:
    def __init__(self, canvas, distSlider, point):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.distSlider = distSlider
        distSlider.configure(command=self.updateDistEvent)
        self.distance = distSlider.get()
        self.point = point
        self.coords, self.length = drawCoords(self.point, self.distance)
        self.midpoint = midpoint(self.coords)
        self.id = canvas.create_line(self.coords, width = 2)
    def updateDistEvent(self, event):
        newDistance = self.distSlider.get()
        self.draw(newDistance)
    def draw(self, newDistance):
        self.canvas.delete(self.id)
        self.distance = newDistance
        self.coords, self.length = drawCoords(self.point, self.distance)
        self.midpoint = midpoint(self.coords)
        self.id = self.canvas.create_line(self.coords, width = 2)
        pass

class Point:
    def __init__(self, initx, inity):
        self.x = initx
        self.y = inity

class Beam:
    def __init__(self, canvas, start, end, endObj):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.id = self.canvas.create_line(self.start.x, self.start.y, self.end.x, self.end.y)
    def draw(self):
        pass

root = Tk()
gui_r = GUI(root)
root.update()

mainCanvas = root.children['!frame'].children['!canvas'];
distSlider = root.children['!frame'].children['!scale'];

center = Point(round(mainCanvas.winfo_width()/2),round(mainCanvas.winfo_height()/2))
mirror = Mirror(mainCanvas, distSlider, center)
source = Point(0, center.y)
beam = Beam(mainCanvas, source, mirror.midpoint, mirror)

root.mainloop()
```

I've omitted any attempts at updates in the Beam class to avoid even more bloat in the code section, but it was literally just taking arguments of `mirror` object passed to `beam`, then the same method as in the Mirror class with different coordinates in `create_line()`.

Comment: you should use `self` in `GUI` - `self.bg` and `self.dist` - and then you have `mainCanvas = gui_r.bg` and `distSlider = gui_r.dist`

Comment: I would create `Mirror` inside `GUI` and bind function to `Scale` which change `Mirror` when Scale change value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create `Mirror` and `Beam` inside `GUI` so they have direct access to `Canvas` and `Scale`. And `GUI` has direct access to `Mirror` and `Beam` so I can assign function to `Scale` which has access to `Mirror` to change it, and to get other its attribiut and use it in `Beam`.

Maybe this way `Beam` doesn't depend directly on `Mirror` but it is easier to create.

```
from tkinter import *

def drawCoords(point, distance):
    mirrorX = distance
    mirrorY = point.y
    mirrorLen = 50;
    return [mirrorX, mirrorY - mirrorLen, mirrorX, mirrorY + mirrorLen], mirrorLen;

def midpoint(coords):
    return Point(round((coords[2]+coords[0])/2),round((coords[3]+coords[1])/2));


class GUI:
    def __init__(self,master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

        self.bg = Canvas(frame, width = 400, height = 400, background = "#F0F0F0", borderwidth = 3, relief = SUNKEN)
        self.bg.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

        self.dist = Scale(frame, from_ = 100, to = 200, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        self.dist.pack(fill = X, expand = 1)

        self.dist.configure(command=self.update_figures)

        root.update()

        self.center = Point(round(self.bg.winfo_width()/2),round(self.bg.winfo_height()/2))
        self.mirror = Mirror(self.bg, self.dist.get(), self.center)

        self.source = Point(0, self.center.y)
        self.beam = Beam(self.bg, self.source, self.mirror.midpoint, self.mirror)

    def update_figures(self, event):
        self.mirror.draw(self.dist.get())
        self.beam.draw(self.mirror.midpoint)


class Mirror:

    def __init__(self, canvas, distance, point):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.distance = distance
        self.point = point
        self.coords, self.length = drawCoords(self.point, self.distance)
        self.midpoint = midpoint(self.coords)
        self.id = canvas.create_line(self.coords, width=2)

    def draw(self, distance):
        self.distance = distance
        self.coords, self.length = drawCoords(self.point, self.distance)
        self.midpoint = midpoint(self.coords)
        # move in new place without deleting
        self.canvas.coords(self.id, self.coords)


class Point:
    def __init__(self, initx, inity):
        self.x = initx
        self.y = inity


class Beam:

    def __init__(self, canvas, start, end, endObj):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.id = self.canvas.create_line(self.start.x, self.start.y, self.end.x, self.end.y)

    def draw(self, end):
        self.end = end
        # move in new place without deleting
        self.canvas.coords(self.id, (self.start.x, self.start.y, self.end.x, self.end.y))


root = Tk()
gui_r = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

---

Other method could but

- put `Mirror` in `GUI` so `Scale` could change Mirror
- put `Beam` in `Mirror` so `Mirror` could change `Beam` when it is changed